# Получаю ошибку в Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

```
    public class Left extends Fragment {
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    View view;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.left,null);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser){
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{
                        String json=HttpRequest.getRequest("http://servefffr1.gcsdsm-gps.com/masds1/get_android.php?",
                                "login=141241&pass=12312").getResponse().getResponseText();
                        jsonObject=new JSONObject(json);
                    } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        ListView listView= (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        }
    }
}
```

Получаю ошибку в связи с тем что listView не находит, так как setUserVisibleHint вызывается раньше чем OnCreateView.

А как быть тогда. Если мне надо делать запрос интернета только после того как данный фрагмент станет видимым. Чтобы экономить трафик, хотелось бы узнать как делают опытные люди в таком случае

Exeption тут `ListView listView= (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);`

Я хочу сделать:

1) при видимости 1 фрагмента, сделать запрос на сервер.
2) После запроса добавить данные в адаптер

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вы создали переменную класса `View view` но нигде её не инициализируете. Засим она `null` и выкидывает исключение.
2. Получить разметку фрагмента можно методом `View getView()` класса `Fragment`
3. Если фрагмент во `ViewPager` то его "видимость" можно получить через `OnPageSelectedListener` `ViewPager`-а.

Comment: Что - то я вас не понял. А причем тут это?

По сути я весь код могу в OnCreateView запихать, а толку? Если у меня 3 фрагмента, то все 3 фрагмента при запуске приложения активируются тоесть OnCreateView у всех фрагментов вызовется.

Зачем мне это? зачем мне зря лишний трафик тратить. Поэтому  я хочу делать запрос в интернет только в том случае если тот или иной фрагмент активен. Как это сделать?

Comment: @xTIGRx, вы не раскрываете деталей. Как у вас разом 3 фрагмента отображены?.. И почему вам первые 2 пункта не подходят?.

Comment: Тут что-то полезное: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24934483/3212712